# Google Analytics / AdSense Integration Issues

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, integration

I'm asking this here as I have absolutely no response / joy on the so called AdSense help forum!

I have both an AdSense and GA account but I'm finding it impossible to link them!

In addition, none of my web pages are displaying ads which suggests there is some kind of issue with my AdSense account, despite my AdSense account saying I have active products of Content, AdMob, Mobile content and Search.

If I go to my AdSense page and look at my GA integration, I have all the pages listed but under linked products it says "None" with a link under action simply saying "Link".

Clicking on this "Link" takes me to my GA page expecting me to link AdSense but when I try to do that I receive the "There are no AdSense accounts associated with the Analytics login you're using" message.

I have also installed the "Google Publisher Toolbar" for Chrome which states, when I'm on my own page, that I have both a GA and AdSense account and suggests I link them.

If I then go into my GA account, scroll to Behaviour -> AdSense section, I receive a message "Link your AdSense and Analytics Properties" but nowhere to actually link them.

Please, could someone help me out here as it's doing my head in!

I'm not 100% but I think my AdSense account was originally created using AdMob which, from everything I've read, caused issues in the past.

Any advice and / or help greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Is there the same account with the admin rights in Adsense and GA?

Comment: Yes. The real strange thing is that the Publisher Toolbar knows I have both accounts set up under the same ID as it tells me to link them but I can't because of these silly errors. I'm seriously thinking about switching allegiance and going with someone else for ads. My original AdSense creation was in September 2014 and I'm still waiting for it to be sorted!

Comment: It is hard to say something exact without access to the accounts. Try to ask on Google Product Forum.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my first line in the post is...

"I'm asking this here as I have absolutely no response / joy on the so called AdSense help forum!"

Comment: Have you tried Google Analytics forum's branch?

Comment: I will try that now. Didn't even occur to me to try that route.  Thanks for the tip...